# ActiveMQ JMS queues get very full during long performance runs

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, performance-testing

I'm running ActiveMQ 5.16.3, and I'm testing a Java-based order management application which runs across several JVMs. These JVMs each do work to push orders through a status pipeline. For example, one JVM creates orders, one schedules orders, and so forth. JDBC is used to store data, and JMS is used to process work between the JVMs. One JVM will read work from the database and put up to 5000 messages into a JMS queue for another JVM to process and do its own work. I am running just one ActiveMQ server with many JMS queues. I have not changed how ActiveMQ is storing messages so whatever is the default is what is being used (which should be KahaDB). JDBC is used only by the Java application.

We support several different JMS vendors other than ActiveMQ (such as Weblogic JMS and IBM MQ). However, only with ActiveMQ I am finding that for longer running or high volume tests the JMS queues start to back up and sometimes have hundreds of thousands of messages in them. There is no where near that much work in the system so something else is going on. Via JMX I've confirmed that the ActiveMQ console is correctly showing the numbers. This behavior seems random in that it's not all JVMs doing this (though all JVMs conceptually do the same thing) and if I stop the work generators (so that the JVMs only process what is already in the queue), the queues usually empty out quickly.

For example, if I want to make 10k orders, 10k messages would go into the first JMS queue for the create order JVM to process. This JVM would then update the JDBC database to create the orders and insert records that the next JVM (in this case, schedule order) would then pick up. The schedule JVM reads from the database and based on what work it sees, puts messages into the next JMS queue (only up to 5k, then it waits for it to empty, then fetches 5k more) for it to process. What I am seeing is that the schedule order JMS queue is filling up far past 10k messages.

My studies have lead me to the possibility of uncommitted reads and concurrency but I've come to a dead end. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: It's 5.16.3 - I'll update the question to include this.

Comment: ActiveMQ generally outperforms both Weblogic JMS and IBM MQ. Run the test with KahaDB backend and see if you get the same results. Perf testing ActiveMQ with a JDBC backend vs others using local storage is an apples-to-oranges perf test. Also, which db server vendor? Oracle, MariaDB, MySQL, etc?

Comment: The databases we support are both DB2 and Oracle. Unfortunately I am just a QA tester for our application so I do not have a say in our code nor our middleware. I'm a huge fan of ActiveMQ and have been pushing it in our application for a while. We do officially support it but most of our customers are using Weblogic JMS or IBM MQ so there is little dev interest. I'm searching to see if there's any ActiveMQ configuration I can change to resolve this behavior. I'm not sure if there's anything in our Java code that could help resolve this - if there is I could bring that to the developers.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I have not changed how ActiveMQ is storing messages so whatever is the default is what is being used (which should be KahaDB). The JDBC database is used only by the Java application.

Comment: For example, if I want to make 10k orders, 10k messages would go into the first JMS queue for the create order JVM to process. This JVM would then update the JDBC database to create the orders and insert records that the next JVM (in this case, schedule order) would then pick up. The schedule JVM reads from the database and based on what work it sees, puts messages into the next JMS queue (only up to 5k, then it waits for it to empty, then fetches 5k more) for it to process. What I am seeing is that the schedule order JMS queue is filling up far past 10k messages.

Comment: Good idea, just updated the question.